# Add google markers from json file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mean-stack

I'm trying to add markers into google maps from an external local json file but I'm having trouble. At the moment I'm getting them like this;

```
    app.get('/markers', function(req, res){
    var query = Marker.find({});
    query.exec(function(err, markers){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(markers);
```

Any suggestions how I could get them from the external json file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the json from another server into your server u should use the **request** module https://www.npmjs.com/package/request